# Android Studio : how to copy/paste a .sfb file from one project to another?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sceneform

I have got a project (implementing Sceneform) that contain sfb files in the raw folder.

I want to copy/past these sfb files to another project. But when I paste them, the content is no more readable even if the file is ok in the 3D preview window.

How to copy/paste a .sfb file from one project to another ?

Comment: You can try to access the files from your explorer, in project's path, copy from there and paste them to the new one

Comment: Hi. Also doesn't work when I copy/paste the file thanks to the OSX Finder. :(

Comment: With a little search, in google developers has a tutorial about importing custom assets in projects. Check this: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets#using_custom_materials

Comment: Thanks but not what I wanted. I wanted to copy paste these assets from from one project to another. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution. You have to create a sampledata folder like explained here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets

And copy/paste also all your sfa, fbx, bin, etc.. files here.

And then the text in the sfb file will become readable.